# Can I run ionic on desktop?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

in the past I've used Phonegap in order to run my Javascript HTML CSS code on mobile devices.

Can I do the same thing with ionic?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand so far from Ionic :

- You build your app with HTML/SASS/AngularJS/ui-router, so it's still the same process, Cordova parsing and "turning" a web app into a native one.
- Ionic CLI provides simulators launching (iDevices simulators require OS X XCode, Android simulators require GenyMotion) with optional livereload, physical devices (just plug them), and desktop web browser also with livereload.
- I think you can have the livereload simultaneously on a device simulator and the web browser, and possibly a physical device, so you're continually testing/debugging as you code.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic uses Cordova (aka Phonegap). Ionic is the user interface controls for hybrid apps, which still use Cordova to build to mobile devices.

You can preview your app while you build on your desktop by using the Ionic CLI. http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/install.html

`ionic serve`

Comment: Ionic is not phonegap. It's true to say that they both use Cordova as their engine, isn't it?
If I'm building a todo list, will I be able to run it on desktop as well? And not just for testing, but giving users the ability to use this "app" on a regular site?

Comment: You could deploy the Angular/Ionic parts of your app (basically the contents of the www directory) to a server. However, the UI components are primarily designed for a mobile device. You can see one of my book examples at https://ionic-in-action-chapter4.herokuapp.com/ to see how while it works, it is not necessarily ideal for desktop use cases.

Comment: OK,
So If I want to build a small chat app or to do list app and let my users to use it on mobile devices AND on desktop (thought about ionic + firebase), then Ionic isn't a good choice?

Comment: I'm pretty happy building a web app using Ionic. It will be primarily accessed by desktops. The only thing Ionic does not have is a grid for resolutions above tablets. I found that Ionic and angular-material play pretty well together. Angular material forces you to use preset values for flexboxes, which is a good thing. I use Ionic for the structure it give to my projects. I can customize the UI with just a few overrides, and make the whole thing more ore less flat. I can also test/develop on native. [Using this technique](https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/) makes responsive design easier.

Comment: Here are some things to consider, as a blog post. http://ionicinaction.com/blog/ionic-is-designed-for-mobile-not-desktop/